# jquery and mysql

Tags: jquery-ui, slider

I have 10 records in my Mysql database and i am using Jquery slider contorl, so i want to set the max value to exactly the same in the number of records in the database... for example if i insert some more records in the database by 3, the slider should take max value as 13 automically... can anyone please help me

---

$(function () { var select = $(#minbeds"); min: 1, max :5, and soon bla bla ba so i want the code which takes in the value for max from the mysql. plz help me out

Answer (score 3):

Get the count of the rows with a server side language like PHP and use that value in the javascript

Comment: <script> $(function () { var select = $(#minbeds"); min: 1, max :5, and soon bla bla ba</script> so i want the code which takes in the value for max from the mysql. plz help me out

Comment: @Bob SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_name would be enough most likely, although i don't know the design of your database